# Replacing a UIView in a StackView does not replace the view but just changes the pointer to it?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uistackview

I am working with `UIStackViews` and I encountered an interesting issue which I am not able to understand by myself.

I think it is just a misunderstanding on my side in terms of memory management and addresses, but I would like a confirmation and a explanation if that is not the case.

I created a project here to showcase the issue:
https://github.com/racer1988/UIKitMemoryAddressTest

I create a `UILabel`, I add it in a `UIStackView` and I can use my variable pointing to the label to edit its values, and the view reflects my changes.

Now, if I create a new `UILabel` and assign it to the original pointer.. For some weird reason, *my mind wants it to replace the Label in the view too.*

Instead.. the variable just starts pointing to the new View and the other one is left in the `UIStackView` unchanged.

**The `UIStackView` has a strong reference to the view in his hierarchy?**)

**What would be the best way to replace a complex view in a `UIStackView`?**
(let's imagine a very complex view with lot of data that cannot be just edited as a label.text)

The best way that comes to my mind is:

1. removing the view from the superview (the stackview)
2. create a new view with the new complex properties
3. add this new view in the correct place as a arranged subview of the stackview (or whatever container we are using)

There is not a less cumbersome way?

**Code:**

```
// Let's Create a Label, and add it to a StackView
theLabel = UILabel()
theLabel.textAlignment = .Center
theLabel.text = "FIRST LABEL"
mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(theLabel)
print(mainStackView.subviews)
// Here the address of the label, in the StackView
// [<UILabel: 0x7fdc32d16150; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'FIRST LABEL'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fdc32e56020>>]

// Let's change the text of the label
theLabel.text = "CHANGED FIRST LABEL"
// The UI is of course correctly edited!
print(mainStackView.subviews)
// Address is of course the same, text is of course changed.
// [<UILabel: 0x7fdc32d16150; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'CHANGED FIRST LABEL'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fdc32e56020>>]

// HERE HERE!!!
// Let's replace the UILabel with a new one!
// Does this only change the variable as a pointer ???

// Let's see the address of the original label
print(unsafeAddressOf(theLabel))
// 0x00007fdc32d16150
// Let's make a second pointer to the same label
let theLabelPointerCopy = theLabel

// Let's create a new label
theLabel = UILabel()
theLabel.text = "Second Label"
print(unsafeAddressOf(theLabel))
// 0x00007fdc32e5b560
print(unsafeAddressOf(theLabelPointerCopy))
// 0x00007fdc32d16150

// Address has changed, but not for the copy and not in the stackview (makes sense, partially to me)

print(mainStackView.subviews)
// Same as before
// [<UILabel: 0x7fdc32d16150; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'CHANGED FIRST LABEL'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fdc32e56020>>]

theLabelPointerCopy.text = "I Can still change what it is in the stackview"
```

Comment: @matt : as written in the question itself, let's imagine a very complex view with lot of data that cannot be just edited as a label.text

Comment: @matt we are just discussing with colleagues the best way to reset a queueable cell with a really complex ui inside, without removing all the views, recreating them and readding them again, which seems slow. However we also think it would be quite a lot of effort to manually edit all the values of the UI etc.. So creating new elements seems the faster route

Comment: no, it is the same exact cell, with a huge UI inside and a lot a lot of different things. The question arises since we were wondering why it would take so many lines of code to recreate a cell, due to having to remove all elements, recreate them, configure them and add them again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125427/discussion-between-marco-pappalardo-and-matt).

Comment: was there any magical solution that you've found for replacing the view inside the stack?

Comment: @Varun sorry it's been 7 years and i really have no memory of the solution.